# codeigniter 404 function is not woking when function calling inside controller

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I have set 404_override in route.php so that when there is no correspondent controller it will redirect to my error page

But my question is if there is no function inside the controller it is not redirecting properly

example: http:example.com/search/function_name
here search controller is there but the function_name not exist, how I can redirect to error page in this scenario ?

Your help will be really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up the 404_override properly it will work as intended. You need to pass the controller method in which you are showing your custom 404 page else it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Create 'index' function in your error controller. Then you do not have to mention the function name in 404_override.